# How to set a postgres configuration with Diesel? I'm trying get RLS to work

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I have this "almost" working. I have setup all the infrastructure in my migrations:

```sql
-- tenant
CREATE TABLE tenant (
    tenant_id int primary key generated always as identity,
    name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
    status VARCHAR(64) CHECK (status IN ('active', 'suspended', 'disabled'))
);

-- Turn on RLS
ALTER TABLE tenant ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

-- Restrict read and write actions so tenants can only see their rows
-- This policy implies a WITH CHECK that matches the USING clause
CREATE POLICY tenant_isolation_policy ON tenant
USING (tenant_id = current_setting('app.current_tenant')::int);
```

```sql
-- tenant_user
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto; -- needed for password

CREATE TABLE tenant_user (
    user_id int primary key generated always as identity,
    tenant_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES tenant (tenant_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    given_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL CHECK (given_name <> ''),
    family_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL CHECK (family_name <> ''),
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    is_verified BOOL DEFAULT 'f',
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

-- Restrict read and write actions so tenants can only see their rows
-- This policy implies a WITH CHECK that matches the USING clause
ALTER TABLE tenant_user ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

-- Restrict read and write actions so tenants can only see their rows
-- This policy implies a WITH CHECK that matches the USING clause
CREATE POLICY tenant_user_isolation_policy ON tenant_user
USING (tenant_id = current_setting('app.current_tenant')::int);
```

This is the part I can't figure out how to get working with Diesel. I can do this from my SQL editor;

```sql
-- with super-user account
INSERT INTO tenant (name, status) VALUES ('tenant1', 'active');
INSERT INTO tenant (name, status) VALUES ('tenant2', 'active');
```

```sql
-- with non super-user account
SET app.current_tenant = 1;
INSERT INTO tenant_user (email, password, tenant_id, given_name, family_name) VALUES ('test@example.com', crypt('test', gen_salt('bf')), 1, 'Test', 'User');
SELECT * FROM tenant_user WHERE ('test@example.com' in (email)) AND password = crypt('test', password);
-- I get back the user I created
SET app.current_tenant = 2;
SELECT * FROM tenant_user WHERE ('test@example.com' in (email)) AND password = crypt('test', password);
-- I don't get back the user, this is what I expected
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to do the `SET` configuration from Diesel. I tried something like this:

```rust
let sql = "SET app.current_tenant = 1";
let query = sql_query(sql);
let result = query.execute(&conn);
```

Which seems to run, but then my follow-up query does not return successfully as I was expecting:

```rust
sql_function!(fn crypt(passwd: Text, salt: Text) -> Text);
tenant_user::table()
  .filter(email.eq(msg.email))
  .filter(password.eq(crypt(msg.password, password)))
  .get_result::<TenantUser>(&conn)
```

My query does work if I run it with the super-user account.  So I think I'm missing something.  Either my `SET` command is not running properly or I'm missing something else.  Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question does not contain all relevant information. Please try to provide a minimal reproducible example. This should include information about the used diesel and rust version and the complete context where your query is called.

Comment: @weiznich thank you for your comment. I spent a bunch of time trying to create a small test case, and the test case worked as expected.  So I went back to my project, and it is working as expected there.  I must have had a typo in my credentials or something.